# Can the PostbackUrl be set for a GridView CommandField?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, postback

I have a GridView control on my page that I have defined a number of BoundFields for.  Each row of the databound GridView has a CommandField (Select), for which I want to send the PostBack to a new page.

Of course I could easily send the NewSelectedIndex in a QueryString, but I'd rather keep that information hidden from the user.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leppie is right. The GridView has no PostbackUrl property. However, you can do what you want by using a standard  control, which has a PostbackUrl property.

```
<asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Edit">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnEdit" PostBackUrl="~/Default.aspx" OnClientClick='form1.ActivityId.value = this.Tag;' Tag='<%# Eval("ActivityId") %>' Text="Edit"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In this sample code, I added a TemplateColumn to the GridView. I use a dynamically added Tag attribute for the button to pass the Id, then I use Javascript code to put the value in a hidden field, and then the button simply postsback to the page specified in the PostbackUrl property.

Answer (score 0):

Use a HyperLinkField column in your GridView:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField AccessibleHeaderText="Edit" DataNavigateUrlFields="ActivityId" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="AcitivtyEdit.aspx?id={0}" Text="Edit Activity" />
```

Of course, as you said, this option shows the id in the url.
To hide it (although anyone can check out your javascript and see what you do) you have two options:
1. Use Javascript code to set a hidden field with the id, change the Form postback (action) address and then submit the form. You have to allow your asp.net site to allow postback from a different page
2. Allow the Command to postback to the same page that hosts the GridView and in the server side event handler to a Server.Transfer to your page (this option presents otehr issues on sequential postbacks...)

Comment: If you do those tricks, ASP.NET will throw an exception. Try before you advise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sergiu Damian.

I use MasterPages and the UniqueID os hidden field may vary. I need post two values.
In the event Gridview_RowDataBound i put this code:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
   e.Row.Cells(12).Text = ""
   Dim img As New WebControls.ImageButton
   img.PostBackUrl = "NecesidadesPostBack.aspx"
   img.ImageUrl = "imagenes/edit.png"
   img.OnClientClick = HDLB.UniqueID.ToString & ".value = '" & e.Row.Cells(0).Text & "'; " & HDPT.UniqueID.ToString & ".value = '" & e.Row.Cells(1).Text & "';"
   img.AlternateText = "Edit"
   e.Row.Cells(12).Controls.Add(img)
End If
```

I have 2 hidden fields (HDLB and HDPT). The event OnClientClick modify the value of this hidden fields with the value of the first and second cell onto the grid.